# What will happen if a string has no NUL character in C/C++ (in case the compiler would let it pass)?

Tags: c++, c, string

What happens all, if a string would have no NUL-character (\0) and the compiler would let it pass, f.e. just with warnings? How does it affect the computer and the program exactly?

Comment: If it has no `NUL` terminator, then it isn't a C string. But note that `char str[5] = "Hallo";` has no `NUL` terminator but  `char str[] = "Hallo";` does.

Comment: The compiler can only enforce null-termination for string literals or character arrays without explicit size that are initialized with a literal string. Nothing stops you from creating an array of characters and not ending it with a null-terminator, but using it as a null-terminated byte string will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: A C string is an array of characters terminated by a NUL character; if we don't have that character, we do not have a string.

Comment: Compiler is not required to do anything for you here, and I can't think of any that do. Usually the first warning that you've screwed up and not terminated a string is a spray of nonsense on the console or a crash. Tonnes of code sneaks out into the wild with bugs like this to the eternal shame of the programmers because they got unlucky and the code seemed to do what they expected.

Comment: Please pick one language tag. In C++, `std::string` doesn't care if you have a null or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A compiler will let it pass as its completly legit. A C-String is nothing else than an array of char and functions just need the `\0` to determine the end of the array, as this is unknown in most cases.

Having no terminator in your c-string will result in functions not beeing able to determine the end of the string and enter undefined behaviour. either a crash due to a segmentation fault or maybe it reads random chars from memory that is located after the string until it eventuelly finds a 0 byte.

So all in all: Passing an array of char as a C-String to a function that expects a null-terminator results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

> What will happen if a string has no NUL character in C/C++

Nothing in particular. Existence of a value does not cause things to happen, and does not affect the behaviour of the program in any way.

It is not until the value is used in some way that it can affect the program. If for example you pass a non-null-terminated string into a standard function whose pre-condition is that the argument is a null-terminated string, then you have violated said pre-condition and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

If you don't try to use a non-null-terminated string as if it were null terminated, then there will be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, and you'll see one possible outcome.

```
char foo[3] = {'f', 'o', 'o'};

std::cout << foo << std::endl;
```

As mentioned, in C++ legalese, this is UB, **so anything could happen**. I'm not recommending relying on this. In practice, the C++ library code for outputting will happily walk past the end of the string and, with high-probability, encounter a 0 char, before hitting memory that is not mapped to your process. So, you get extra output like:

```
fooP^%&%#.~2blah
```

But if you try it in production code, obviously there will be no 0 char, or the compiler will have chosen this day to make a smart optimization and you program will crash or worse.

Comment: Recommend a wording change. Undefined behaviour is a horrible thing to suggest just trying it. It might work.

Comment: Correct, it doesn't prove anything. But experimenting and actually caring about what the compiler does, how the memory is laid out, etc. might prove more useful to learners than relying (somewhat) blindly on the C++ language rules.

Comment: As long as you don't know the compiler and version you don't know if the learner will learn the mentioned topics. Undefined behaviour means that the built program could always order a pizza. You can't even be sure that the garbage that is printed is actual memory. It could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print that, it will (**in most cases**) print some "garbage" after string, but the ***behaviour is undefined***.

Comment: Perhaps it will ... noone can say for sure. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: or it may crash, or explode a supernova in the Andromeda galaxy, or ... ...

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. The behaviour is completly undefined and is up to the compiler and/or the operating system and even on the data that is in RAM after the C-String.